# Passing boost smart pointers by reference

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

The following function converts a `Container` that I use in my code to one required by a c interface. I'm having to pass in a `boost::shared_array<CValues>&` to this function since I need to keep its associated memory alive until I use the cContainer. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
CContainer getCContainer(const Container& container, boost::shared_array<CValues>& values)
{
    CContainer cContainer;
    cContainer.type = boost::apply_visitor(CTypeGetter(), container);
    cContainer.nrOfValues = boost::apply_visitor(ContainerSizeGetter(), container);
    values = boost::shared_array<CValues>(new CValues[cContainer.nrOfValues]);
    boost::apply_visitor(ValueSetter(values), container);
    cContainer.values = values.get();
    return cContainer;
}

void store(Container& container)
{
    boost::shared_array<CValue> values;
    CContainer cContainer = getCContainer(container, values);
    cSave(cContainer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would return it, instead of passing in a parameter. I assume that a `shared_array` just copies pointers around, so it is cheap and better states what you are doing. The copy should be elided anyway.

Comment: What if someone forgets to assign the returned shared_array to a variable? Then it will be deallocated before its associated memory is used.

Comment: @Baz Very good point. Do you own `CContainer`? Why does it take a pointer rather than own its data?

Comment: I own CContainer and should deallocate its memory. I haven't written the C interface...

Comment: Why not change the interface of `CContainer` to take a `shared_array`? I have to say, I don't like your naming scheme...